# from string to integer (scripts)

Tags: scripting, csh, tcsh

I have this snippet of the code:

```
 set calls = `cut -d" " -f2 ${2} | grep -c "$numbers"`
 set messages = `cut -d" " -f2 ${3} | grep -c "$numbers"`

 @ popularity = (calls * 3) + messages
```

and error

```
@ expression syntax
```

what does it mean? `grep -c` returns number, am I wrong, thanks in advance

in $numbers I have list of numbers, 2 and 3 parameters also contain numbers

Comment: Which line causes that error?

Comment: I don't know, can I check it, didn't know, how?

Comment: Try "echo $numbers" to see if you're passing grep no arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@ popularity = ($calls * 3) + $messages
```

The $ symbols are still needed to indicate variables.

See [C-shell Cookbook](http://www.starlink.rl.ac.uk/star/docs/sc4.htx/node30.html)